# Upper cases (superscript) in ggplot (R) at x-axis?

Tags: ggplot2

How I can make x axis text like 1st, 2st, 3rd, 4th superscripted in R?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `expression()` for that.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width^2)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Sepal.length", y=expression(Sepal.Width^2), title="Title")

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width^2)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Sepal.length", y=expression(Sepal.Width^"3rd"), title="Title")
```

Is that what you need?